# Self Executing functions in PHP5.3?

Tags: php, lambda, closures, php-5.3

I was trying to borrow some programing paradigms from JS to PHP (just for fun).
Is there a way of doing:

```
$a = (function(){
  return 'a';
})();
```

I was thinking that with the combination of `use` this can be a nice way to hide variables JS style

```
$a = (function(){
    $hidden = 'a';
    return function($new) use (&$hidden){
        $hidden = $new;
        return $hidden;
    };
})();
```

right now I need to do:

```
$temp = function(){....};
$a = $temp();
```

It seems pointless...

Comment: hard to understand for me... :) what exactly you meant..

Comment: I'm a little confused what you're trying to accomplish or why you want to execute functions this way. Although I'm pretty sure there is no way to encapsulate a function like that in PHP. Functions in javascript are implemented as classes, whereas in PHP they are actual functions. For this reason they all exist within a global namespace, not within their self-contained namespace. The closest thing to a "self-calling function" I could imagine would be to define the function within `eval()`

Comment: XiroX: would you perhaps consider asking a question?

Comment: PHP5.3 have lambda support, and so I wanted to know if there was a way of invoking them without assigning them to a variable.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

[Function Call Chaining, e.g. `foo()()` is in discussion for PHP5.4.](http://wiki.php.net/rfc/fcallfcall) Until then, use `call_user_func`:

```
$a = call_user_func(function(){
    $hidden = 'a';
    return function($new) use (&$hidden){
        $hidden = $new;
        return $hidden;
    };
});

$a('foo');    
var_dump($a);
```

gives:

```
object(Closure)#2 (2) {
  ["static"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["hidden"]=>
    string(3) "foo"
  }
  ["parameter"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["$new"]=>
    string(10) "<required>"
  }
}
```

As of PHP7, you can immediately execute anonymous functions like this:

```
(function() { echo 123; })(); // will print 123
```

Comment: Would you possibly be able to update this? Would be appreciated.

Comment: Terrific, I have no doubt this will be a value to the community and future googlers.

Comment: FYI, function call chaining (which allows `(function () {...})();`) does not work in PHP 5.6.