# Closure within a string in PHP

Tags: php, closures, anonymous-function

I want to create and execute a closure within a string in PHP and it's not liking the way that I do it.

This code doesn't work...

```
echo ( 'Hello, ' . (function($s) { return $s; })('World!') );
```

Yet, this is completely valid and works as intended...

```
$f = (function($s) { return $s; });
echo ( 'Hello, ' . $f('World!') );
```

Why won't the first one work and is there a way to do it in one line (not because I think it's efficient, because I'm sure it's not)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Self Executing functions in PHP5.3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865934/self-executing-functions-in-php5-3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [Self Executing functions in PHP5.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865934/self-executing-functions-in-php5-3).

Essentially, no self-invoking with "(...)()" until (maybe) sometime in 5.4.

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/fcallfcall

Comment: @KevinHikaruEvans because the feature status is still 'under discussion' - https://wiki.php.net/rfc/fcallfcall

Comment: Oh alright, thanks. I guess I'll have to declare functions the old fashioned way then.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Added the link provided from the top answer in the linked question. As Jack said, the feature is still just discussion,

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's only possible in PHP 5.4: http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php