# Is there a single execution function in php like in js

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Anonymous functions that execute immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568410/anonymous-functions-that-execute-immediately)

javascript code:

```
(function(){
  var msg = 'Hello World';
  console.log(msg);
})();
```

Is there an equivalent way to do this in php?

Comment: Self Executing functions in PHP5.3? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865934/self-executing-functions-in-php5-3

Comment: Maybe the anonymous functions is what are looking for: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: Not sure what yet are trying to accomplish. Can you reword the question

Comment: What's your intention? In JS it is usually done for scoping or creating new variables to work around issues with closures. Is that what you intend to do in your PHP code, too?

Comment: as @gordon says in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865934/self-executing-functions-in-php5-3 Function Call Chaining, e.g. foo()() is in discussion for PHP5.4. Until then, use call_user_func:

Comment: and here: "Anonymous functions that execute immediately" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568410/anonymous-functions-that-execute-immediately

Answer (score 0):

The pattern in your example is used to overcome issues with function-level static scoping in javascript. There is no equivalent pattern in PHP, since PHP has no such issues.

You might as well just create a new class.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible:

```
call_user_func(function() {
  $localvar = 'foo';
  echo $localvar;
});
```

And while I agree that it has less value in PHP than in JS, there are use cases, i.e. procedural include files. For further description of the method, see [my blog](http://www.schmengler-se.de/anonymous-function-calls-in-php).

Comment: that's what i'v been looked for thank's